# Display records that are not present in a table and a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, datetime

Let's say I have two tables - Student and Student Attendance tables. The Student table displays basic information about the student:

| Student# | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201710 | John | Smith |
| 201711 | John | Doe |
| 201712 | Anna | Sy |
| 201713 | Chris | Dy |

While the Student Attendance table displays the TimeIn and TimeOut of the student from class:

| Student# | Date | TimeIn | TimeOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201710 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201711 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201712 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201713 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201710 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201711 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201712 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201710 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201712 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201713 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |

My objective is to also include the Student #s of the students who do not have logs for that day, which I will use to determine that they are absent.

| Student# | Date | TimeIn | TimeOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201710 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201711 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201712 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201713 | 2016-01-06 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201710 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201711 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201712 | 2016-01-07 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201713 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 201710 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:00.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201711 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 201712 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:10.000 | 00:15:00.000 |
| 201713 | 2016-01-08 | 00:09:05.000 | 00:15:00.000 |

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Use a Calendar Table, `CROSS JOIN` to your `Student` Table, and then `LEFT JOIN` to your `Attendance` Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need  to create a **Calendar table** to populate the required date, and then `CROSS JOIN` it with the `Students` table.

After that, left join the `StudentsAttendance` table with the result set.

**Calendar table:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Cal(AttDate DATE)
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2016-01-06', @MaxDate DATE = '2016-01-08'

WHILE @MinDate<=@MaxDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Cal
    SELECT @MinDate

    SET @MinDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@MinDate)
END
```

This table hold the below dates.

```
AttDate
2016-01-06
2016-01-07
2016-01-08
```

Now execute the query

```
SELECT D.Student#,D.AttDate,SA.TimeIn, SA.TimeOut
FROM(
    SELECT S.Student#, AttDate
    FROM #Cal C
    CROSS JOIN Student S
    )D
LEFT JOIN Student_Attendance SA ON SA.Student# = D.Student# AND SA.Date = D.AttDate
ORDER BY D.AttDate,D.Student#
```

Try this, and let us know if you are getting any error.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/73070/1)

Comment: Hi! thank you so much, I thought using a left join between the two tables would suffice. Will study more on this one and keep this in mind! :) I really appreciate the help!